# AudioToolBox AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer implementation file is not present

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, audiotoolbox, remoteio

I am using realtime audio rendering with `Audio Unit RemoteIO` and I need to do sample rate conversions to ensure that my rendering is the same sample rate as hardware specification. Eg. in iPhone 12 sample rate is 48khz but in iPhone 8 its 44.1khz.

To do this sample rate conversion I am using `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` method. However there is a catch. In order to ensure I do not get any underruns I would like to check `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` methods source code to see whether memory allocations are made with `new` keyword. It is a requirement that since mem alloc is blocking it should never be used inside a remote io callback.

Is there a way to access `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` function from `AudioToolBox`'s source code? In xcode I can only see the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is private to Apple but both `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` and the C++ side of `AudioConverter` are used directly by IOProcs so there should be no problem calling that function from a real time context.

Here is a screenshot from the render block of an `AVAudioSourceNode`:
[image: call stack]

Comment: This is an elegant demonstration.